# Artificial folk with ovine dreams

Tags: riddle, wordplay, rhyme

> > Those artificial folk with ovine dreams,
> > under attack by some fighting machines,
> > there is no try, or whatever that means.
>
> What are we ?
>
> > Icelandic suffix denoting one's kin,
> > addressing the priest while confessing one's sin,
> > a bottle of vodka or whisky or gin.
>
> What are we?
>
> > 2, 4 and 8, 16 and 32,
> > XCI (wait, that should be 92),
> > something between the two O's in O<sub>2</sub>.
>
> What are we?

What am I?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You are

> The Matrix

The first part refers to

> Robots (in particular Blade Runner's Androids, Terminator/Drones and Star Wars' “Not the droids you're looking for“)

MichaelK got part of that first.

The second verse refers to

> The holy **Trinity**

Thanks to Shahriar Mahmud Sajid for that part.

Finally, the third part references

> several **Agents** from different movies.
> These are: Austin *Powers*, Agent *91* (from Get Smart, admittedly a bit reaching) and James *Bond*.

(The first and third line were found by Joseph Mulligan).

All three have in common that

> they appear in the Matrix: The robots built it, Trinity is a main character in the movie and Agents are software programs in it.

Comment: See my updated answer, I think you have it right.

Comment: Nice team effort! This is the intended answer. For the XCI line I had something else in mind - rot13[Ebzna ahzrenyf gung ner n yvggyr "bss"]. For the second line, rot13[tbbtyr "svtugvat znpuvar"] :)

Answer (score 9):

Partial Answer

2, 4 and 8, 16 and 32,

> **Powers** of 2

XCI (wait, that should be 92),

> 92 means 9, twice; or **99**. *Credit to @mohirl*

something between the two O's in O2.

> A molecular **Bond**

Overall

> These are the names of **Spies** in film (*Powers*, Austin Powers; *Bond*, James Bond; *99*, Get Smart).

Comment: If there's a typo,  rot13(KPVK jbhyq tvir lbh Ntrag Avargl-avar (Trg Fzneg)). And actually, maybe "wait that should be 92" indicates it should be rot13(avar gjvpr, fb avargl avar)

Answer (score 8):

**Partial:**
*Icelandic suffix denoting one's kin,

addressing the priest while confessing one's sin,

a bottle of vodka or whisky or gin.*

> this refers to holy trinity in christian faith.
> Icelandic suffix denoting one's kin- **son**,
> addressing the priest while confessing one's sin- **father**,
> a bottle of vodka or whisky or gin - **spirit**.

there is no try, or whatever that means.

> this line probably refers to master yoda from star wars,
> there's a famous dialogue - "Do or do not, there is no try"

Answer (score 5):

Partial:

> Those artificial folk with [ovine](https://www.google.se/search?q=ovine) dreams

...are...

> Androids. This refers to the title: [*Do Androids Dream of Electric Sheep?* by Philip K. Dick](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Do_Androids_Dream_of_Electric_Sheep%3F), which in turn was developed into Bladerunner and Bladerunner 2049, two science fiction movies. The first film was released in the early 1980's and the second was "recently" released.

.

> under attack by some fighting machines

...refers to...

> [Drones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unmanned_aerial_vehicle), or **Terminators**. Terminator is science fiction franchise, spanning from the 1980's and is still ongoing.

.

> there is no try, or whatever that means

...is part of a quote from...

> *The Empire Strikes Back*, a Star Wars film. Star Wars is a science fiction franchise  where "'droids" play an large part. The Empire Strikes Back was released in 1980, and new Star Wars movies are still being released.

Hence the connection is...

> **Science fiction movie franchises involving androids/robots**.

Bonus connection:

> These franchises all span at least four decades.

Comment: I think "under attack by some fighting machines" more likely refers to *Terminator* or something along those lines, which with *Star Wars* might make the triplet "films" or "sci-fi" or something.

Comment: @Obie2.0 Yeah, that makes sense. See the edited answer.

Answer (score 4):

Partial answer (well, final, but without full explanation):

> I think this is about the [Cambridge Five](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cambridge_Five).

Thanks to [Shahriar](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/73649/5373), the middle part is

> TRINITY.

Thanks to [Joseph](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/73652/5373), the last part is

> SPIES.

The connection appears to be

> this famous group of **spies** who were mostly at **Trinity** College Cambridge.

Comment: I think this answer could be justified further because: ROT13(Va Qb Naqebvqf Qernz Bs Ryrpgevp Furrc, Qrpxneq xvyyf *5* Naqebvqf, gurer ner *5* Grezvangbe zbivrf, naq gur yvar 'Gurer vf ab gel' vf fcbxra va Fgne Jnef Rcvfbqr *5*). Putting it all together, we get ROT13(Svir Gevavgl Fcvrf)